# For Loop that loops through row and only adds unique values

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a macro that consists of 2 loops, but I am only looking for help with the second one (named as a comment as "Deal Name For Loop" for your reference). What the second loop does is it goes through my sheets, gathers the value in cell A1 in each sheet, and then places that value in the next(to the right) empty cell in row 4, in another sheet whose name corresponds with what is in the cell I3 in the sheet its looping through. Ill include my code because I understand its a bit confusing.

What I would like this second loop to do, is to not allow duplicate values in row 4. Basically, the macro will be run many times, and I do not want it to compile all the values, from cell A1, into row 4 every time. For now I have been trying to find a way to delete duplicate values in row 4 (as seen towards the end of my code) but I realized that this wouldn't be an effective way of handling the issue. I would rather the For Loop skip the process of copying cell A1 if it reached a sheet whose cell A1 was already in row 4, in the other sheet.

```
Sub AggLoop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim nme As String
    Dim Crng As Range
    Dim HdrCol As Range
    Dim Site As String
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim HdrRow As Range
    Dim FinDate As Date


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 ' Date For Loop
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    nme = ws.Range("I3").Text
    Set rng = ws.Range("T7:T200")

    'Dont Copy Data from these worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Portfolio" And ws.Name <> "Master" And ws.Name <> "Template" And ws.Name <> "Coal" And ws.Name <> "E&P" And ws.Name <> "Gas Gen" And ws.Name <> "Hydro" And ws.Name <> "LNG" And ws.Name <> "Midstream" And ws.Name <> "Solar" And ws.Name <> "Transmission" And ws.Name <> "Wind" Then
    'Storing Copied data into cell (A5)
       If IsEmpty(Sheets(nme).[A1]) Then
       rng.Copy Sheets(nme).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

    'Storing next copied data below previously filled cell
      Else
          rng.Copy Sheets(nme).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
      'Delete duplicates
          Sheets(nme).Range("A4:A200").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
      'Sort by column A
        Sheets(nme).Range("A4:XFD200").Sort key1:=Sheets(nme).Range("A5:A200"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    End If
  End If

Next ws

' Deal Name For Loop
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    nme = ws.Range("I3").Text
    Set Crng = ws.Range("A1")

    'Dont Copy Data from these worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Portfolio" And ws.Name <> "Master" And ws.Name <> "Template" And ws.Name <> "Coal" And ws.Name <> "E&P" And ws.Name <> "Gas Gen" And ws.Name <> "Hydro" And ws.Name <> "LNG" And ws.Name <> "Midstream" And ws.Name <> "Solar" And ws.Name <> "Transmission" And ws.Name <> "Wind" Then
    'Storing Copied data into cell A4
    If IsEmpty(Sheets(nme).[A4]) Then
    Crng.Copy Sheets(nme).Range(4 & Columns.Count).End(xlLeft)
    'Storing next copied data below previously filled cell
      Else
          Crng.Copy Sheets(nme).Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)

    'Delete duplicates, this is the part that I am trying to change, so that the For Loop can ignore rather than delete

          Sheets(nme).Range("D4:XFD4").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(4, 500), Header:=xlNo

    End If
End If

Next ws
```

Comment: You could add the values to a dictionary as you go and check if it it already exists before adding to your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

An option for this is to sort in your second loop and use a third loop for the addition such as:

```
Sheets(nme).Range("A4:XFD200").Sort key1:=Sheets(nme).Range("D5:D200"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Dim i, j, k,l as integer

j=0
k=0
l=0

For i = 6 to 200 'based on your range
    l=l
    k=l
    If Cells(i,4).Value=Cells(i-1,4) Then
        'Nothing
    Else
        j=Cells(i,4).Value
        l=j+k
    End If
Next i

'Output l in the desired cell
```